# Need to define foreign key when migrate in laravel 5.2?

Tags: eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-5

I want to create two tables: supporters and tickets in database. In tickets table, I want to add id of supporters table as foreign key( supports_id in tickets table). But I will not define as foreign key in migration. I read Eloquent relations at Laravel official site, it say 'Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column and  suffix it with _id' . So, I am right or wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't define foreign keys in your migrations, than your database simply does not have any foreign key relations at database level. ( And with that no referential integrity etc... ).

If you are using Eloquent to query your database, you could have a User Model like that:

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

In the case there is a One To One Relationship User <-> Phone.

Here it is assumed, that the phones table has a column with the name 
**user_id**  (modelname + "_" + "id") **that is used for making Joins.**

You are totally free to use your own convention of naming keys and use the function as follows:

```
 public function phone()
 {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Phone','own_key_name');
 }
```

But again: Just using Eloquent does not mean, that your database table have any foreign key constraints. They have to be added in your database migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I always did it as follows

```
 Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('supporters_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('supporters_id')->references('id')->on('supporters')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('ticket_owner');
            ...
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

So the fact that I explicit define a $table->foreign makes me think it's needed. Let me know if you find other evidence it's not needed :-)

Comment: I think eloquent wil automatically determine the proper foreign key column and suffix it with _id' .